# Mysql not ranking results, fulltext

Tags: mysql

I have setup a database and enabled fulltext search, i have some entries in the database that include the word 'test' and one that has 'test some more' when i used the below to search the database:

```
SELECT keywords, title FROM database WHERE Match(keywords) Against ('more test')
```

I was expecting it to rank the entry that had 'test some more' above the one that just had 'test' in it.

Am i doing something wrong maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never specify that the results must be ordered, you simply put an additional constraint on the result that there must be a match.

You can solve this with the following query:

```
SELECT keywords, title,
    MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('more test') AS relevance
FROM database
WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('more test')
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

And as @GordonLinoff mentions, you probably need to disable the stopwords filter by setting `stopwords.txt` variable to the empty string (`''`; but remember the original value to restore it).

Comment: i get the following: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match(keywords) Against ('more test') AS relevance FROM database WHERE Match(ke' at line 1

Comment: Can you give the column number?

Comment: are you talking about the "keywords" column? If so its column 3

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast: No the location in the row where the error occurs. Since the line is quite long, it is hard to debug it entirely.

Comment: It seems to be working now, i retested it with the code you edited. But it is still showing in the wrong order. Like the original problem. Thanks a lot for this btw.

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast: what numbers are mentioned in the `relevance` column?

Comment: It wasnt working because i added a * rather than keywords, title so it bugged out. Relevance shows "0.6852666139602661" for both results

Comment: keywords in first are "test", and in second row is "test some more" i have tried this with other words also

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast: what if you disable the stopwords filter? See updated answer...

Comment: i have tried it with other terms, like "hoops stand" with 2 results 1 "stand with hoops" and other result to be "hoops yeah" and still not ranking properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66853/discussion-between-bubblewrapbeast-and-commusoft).

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL removes certain words from the text search.  These are called "stop words" and they are not in the index.  You can read about them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).  The words "more" and "some" are examples of stop words.

You can provide your own list of stop words, but you will have to recreate the index.